# Join on a collection

Tags: collection

I'm working on a store that only has downloadable products in it. I need to get each customer's downloadable products and be able to sort them by product name and sku. My current code works in retrieving all the download links.

```
$purchasedItems = Mage::getResourceModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('purchased_id', array('in' => $purchasedIds))
            ->addFieldToFilter('status',
                array(
                    'nin' => array(
                        Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PENDING_PAYMENT,
                        Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PAYMENT_REVIEW
                    )
                )
            );
```

However, this does not return the product name nor the sku. So I am attempting a join on the collection to the `catalog_product_flat` table.

```
$productTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product_flat');
$purchasedItems->getSelect()
            ->join(array('products' => $productTableName), 'main_table.product_id = products.entity_id', array('products.*'));
```

Doing a `var_dump($purchasedItems)` returns a `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Link_Purchased_Item_Collection Object`. But I cannot iterate over the `$purchasedItems`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you cannot iterate? Try to get sql `$purchasedItems->getSelect()->__toString()` and execute it directly in mysql. What will be the result?

Comment: I don't have access to the server unforunately. but dumping `$purchasedItems->getSelect()->__toString()` returns `SELECT `main_table`.*, `products`.* FROM `m_downloadable_link_purchased_item` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `m_catalog_product_flat` AS `products` ON main_table.product_id = products.entity_id WHERE (purchased_id IN('2003877', '2003880', '2003883', '2003886', '2003871', '2003874', '2003865', '2003838', '2003841', '2003844', '2003847', '2003850', '2003853', '2003856', '2003859', '2003829', '2003832', '2003835')) AND (status NOT IN('pending_payment', 'payment_review'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'table_alias' doesn't reference any table in your query. For the flat product table, your defined alias is 'products'

Thus, your join code should be like this:

```
$purchasedItems->getSelect()
->join(array('products' => $productTableName), 'main_table.product_id = products.entity_id', array('products.*'));
```

Also, be aware that if you create additional store views you will have multiple flat product tables: 'catalog_product_flat_1' 'catalog_product_flat_2' where 1 and 2 are store codes

Comment: I have updated my question and replaced the `table_alias` with `products`, but I still cannot iterate over them

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to iterate over the items? What do you get if you run "echo $purchasedItems->count()" ?

Comment: I don't get any errors when trying to iterate, just no results. I have tried `foreach ($purchasedItems as $item) {
   Mage::log($item);
  }` which doesn't return anything. Also 'Mage::log($purchasedItems->count());` does not return anything either. But `Mage::log($purchasedItems)` returns a `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Link_Purchased_Item_Collection` object

Comment: This means the collection is empty. Try removing the filters (addFieldToFilter()) and then try again

Comment: Still get nothing after removing the filters

Comment: One last question: what's the result if you don't join with the product flat table?

Comment: if I don't join, I get the collection as I would expect to get it without any problems. I can iterate over it, run `$purchasedItems->count()`, etc.

Comment: I just tried changing the `$productTableName` to `$productTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product')` and the join is working. So maybe it is a problem with the table name?

Comment: Ah, this means one thing: your catalog_product_flat table is empty. Default join is INNER JOIN, which only returns results if both tables contain values that can be joined. You can either use LEFT JOIN, but this will not return product name and sku if the flat table is empty, or you can see why the flat table is doesn't have the values you need. Try reindexing Product Flat Data

Comment: As a response to the table name, it may be. If you have more than 1 store view, than you have to add the store view id to the flat table. getTableName('catalog/product') returns catalog_product_entity as table, which contains the product sku, but not the product name